# exercise in Intermediate value

Tags: calculus

f is continuous function in [0,2] and
$ f(2)=1 $

proof that there is a point $x$ in [0,2] so that:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

nobody in my class solved this exercise. our teacher give us a hint: $ p(x)=x*f(x) $ and to do Intermediate value theorem on this function. so I tried:

$ p(0)=0*f(0)=0 , P(2)=2*f(2)=2 $

$ p(0) < h < p(2) $
by Intermediate value theorem, there is a point c so that $a<c<b$ and $f(c)=h$

I have no idea how to continue from here. I have spent hours on this exercise and I fed up. please solve it, don't write hints :) I will appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be almost done. You know that $p(0) = 0$, $p(2) = 2$ and that $p$ is continuous. You want to find an $x \in [0,2]$ such that $f(x) = 1/x$, in other words $p(x) = 1$. Thus you can set $h=1$ and you know there exists a $c \in [0,2]$ such that $p(c) = 1$. This in turn means $f(c) = 1/c$, so you're done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $p(x) = h$, then

$$f(x) = \frac h x$$

You're free to choose $h$ to be anything between $0$ and $2$, and there's a particularly salient choice of $h$.